# Shiny Action Button

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to do a simple Shiny App in RStudio. Basically a user needs to input a number and I will show this number once user presses "Go". There is a "Refresh" button to reset all user input values to nothing.

**UI.R**

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(

  headerPanel("header"),
  sidebarPanel(
    textInput(inputId = "text1", label="Input Text 1"),
    actionButton("goButton", "Go!"),
    actionButton("refresh", "Restart!")
    ),
  mainPanel(
    p("Output text1"),
    textOutput("text1"),
    p("Output text3"),
    textOutput("text3")

    )
))
```

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {


  output$text1 <- renderText({as.numeric(input$text1)})

  x <- eventReactive(input$goButton, {input$text1})

  output$text3 <- renderText(x())

  observeEvent(input$refresh, {
    updateTextInput(session, 'text1', value="")
    updateTextInput(session, "text3", value="")
  })

})
```

I manage to reset the value of text1 to nothing and rendered it but this changes don't translate to text3. As far as I understand, text3 supposes to grab values from text1 and thus if text1 is "", text3 should be "" too. And Clicking 'refresh' button would render text3 text to nothing.

I am not sure what happened, can anybody help?

Comment: you can not `updateTextInput` text3 which is a `textOutput`...

Comment: That makes sense. How do I clear text3 output then?

Comment: `output$text3 <- renderText("")`

Comment: If I do output$text3 <- renderText(""), I cannot display text3 anymore when I press Go button.